# Regarding 3D Metal Printing: Can magnetic or electrical fields affect density, form or crystallization?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

Good day,
I am curious in regards to 3D metal printing. Can magnetic or electrical fields affect density, form or crystallization form in molten metals? I am interested in fine tuning the precision of 3D metal printing.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try a literature search for "crystallization magnetic field"? I am getting lots of papers on the topic. Not sure it will do much in molten metals with the temperature far above the Curie point. Electric fields and molten metals... well, that's probably mostly electrolytic effects and electromigration. The latter is usually a bad thing.